# design resource for react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We are going to try build an app with react-native for the first time.

We are getting design resources from a different team and they don't have experience with react-native either.

Is there a something that we should request for react-native design resources?

Can you make native app(swift/java based) or react-native app using the same design resources?

I'm not sure this is stackoverflow-ish question, but very real question that I need answer for.

- edit

I removed the question over (psd+guide vs image slices)

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're asking, do you want to get design specifications from a team to create an app in `react-native`? If so, you need to ask your colleagues what they prefer as this question would be too opinion based.

Comment: I understand it might be opinion based, I'm asking it anyway because I & design team are both new to react-native and we don't know if there might be differences how react-native handles design from stock native apps.

Comment: How do you define design resources in this context? But again, this isn't really a question for this forum.

Comment: Suppose you are making your first react-native app, and suppose your design team also have no experience with react-native.  Should I tell designer team to give us design resources in the same format they used to give us? or should I request something different?  (especially when the design team is a separate team outside of our company) . where can I ask this question?

Comment: I'd argue there's no difference in resources used between a `react-native` app and a responsive app developed in Bootstrap/jQuery, assuming I'm understanding your question correctly. The only difference is when making a single page application. In which case, I'm not sure what I'd recommend beyond using PSD/Concept images. That being said, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ MIGHT be able to help.

Comment: @eugene when you said design, you are talking about wireframes, images, fonts and other assets, right? If that's the case, you only need to make sure that the asset format it's supported on the platform you want to deploy, for example, for fonts, TTF works on iOS and Android.

Comment: Oh so design resources for react-native-app would be more of a form of web page rather than of a form of a native app ?